# setting a "value" attribute in html with a variable containing spaces

Tags: javascript, html

I am very new to HTML/JS so I appologize if this is a basic question... I tried to look this up on the web and was unable to find a solution.

I am using a JS code to create an HTML. I am trying to set a "value" attribute with a var containing spaces (string with spaces). when inspecting the value in chrome I can see that the string is not set correctly.

This is my JS code:

```
var templateArray = templateString.split("\t");
for (var i = 0; i < templateArray.length; i++) {
  htmlTemplate.push("<option value="+templateArray[i]+">"+templateArray[i]+"</option>");
}
```

This is the templateArray:

```
templateArray[0] = template_member_information
templateArray[1] = template - member information
```

This is what I get when inspecting in chrome:

```
<option value="template" -="" member="" information="">template - member information</option>
<option value="template_member_information">template_member_information</option>
```

Comment: should `templateArray[1] = template - member information` be `templateArray[1] = "template - member information"` or what are you doing here?

Answer (score 2):

Don't write raw HTML, instead store only the values, then create the DOM elements on the fly.

Assuming you have all the values inside array named `values` have such code to populate a drop down list with items having those values: (and text equal to the value)

```
var oDDL = document.getElementById("MyDropDownList");
for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    var option = new Option();
    option.value = option.text = values[i];
    oDDL.appendChild(option);
}
```

This way you don't have to mess around with quotes and the code is more flexible.

[Live test case](http://jsfiddle.net/k2QTa/).

Comment: Thank you very much! looks much cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you simply put your value between quotes ?

```
htmlTemplate.push("<option value=\""+templateArray[i]+"\">"+templateArray[i]+"</option>");
```

Note that this would still fail with values containing quotes, but there would be less failings.

Comment: well, and let's hope `templateArray[i]` doesn't contain quotes or `<>`s.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the quotes:

```
var str = "<option value='"+templateArray[i]+"'>"+templateArray[i]+"</option>";
htmlTemplate.push(str);
```

Comment: Thanks! I forgot the "'" as mentioned here. (I'm sorry)