# Ignore spaces in html title

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following:

```
var t = some.text; //e.g some.text = "asdf asdf asdf"
var o = other.text;
row += "<td title=" + t + ">" + o + "</td>";
```

Unfortunately t is displayed as `<td title="asdf" asdf="" asdf="">My other text here</td>`

Is there a way to display it as `<td title="asdf asdf asdf">My other text here</td>`?

Comment: Quote the title property—there are spaces in it.

Comment: Don't create HTML by concatenating strings? Use DOM methods like `const td = document.createElement("td"); td.title = t; td.textContent = o;`

Comment: use [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [setting a "value" attribute in html with a variable containing spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14303138/setting-a-value-attribute-in-html-with-a-variable-containing-spaces)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are forgetting to quote the attribute value:

```
row += "<td title=\"" + t + "\">" + o + "</td>";
```

Instead of resulting in `<td title=asdf asdf asdf>` you would get `<td title="asdf asdf asdf">`. However this still isn't fool proof, for example if the title string contains more qoutes, so I would recommend DOM methods instead.

Comment: @space110 Noting that it’s the least-best solution.

Answer (score 1):

with [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) you can rerwite as following:

```js
var t = some.text; //e.g some.text = "asdf asdf asdf"
var o = other.text;
row += `<td title="${t}">${o}</td>`;
```

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful. Learned something new.